# how keep the text box show if it is empty in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a program to hide empty text boxes. I used a checkbox for that. When checking the checkbox then empty text boxes are hidden. Text boxes that have values are keeping.

But now I have a problem. while checkbox are been checked I can not erase the value in the text box to edit. It means when I erase values in the text box to enter new values then that text box is hidden because of it `length` is `0`. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: In your function, where you check for `if (hasQuantities.length === 0)` also check if the element has focus. And if it does, don't hide it.

Comment: If you can ping me on skype, we can fix it together: skype ID: syed_haroon

Comment: @JayNyxed Can you please post this as an answer. Then it will be more understandable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do that:

1. Only update the boolean that filter empty text boxes after they're edited. (i.e. `onblur` event). You could have a boolean that list the text boxes to hide, but only update it after an `onblur` event occurs. So it won't be updated while you write in a text box.
2. Consider a text box empty only if it's empty && it doesn't have current focus (i.e. use the `@focus` event or get the textbox html element with a `$ref` to get the html element and use `document.activeElement === myTextBox`)

This is not a final solution because we don't have enough clues about what does you code look like. But I guess it's a start to resolution :)

Answer (score 0):

As @jaynyxed mentioned, you could use focusin and focusout to help you achieve your goal, I write an example [here in code pen](https://codepen.io/drocha87/pen/dyMxjKQ) and I'll let the code here, so if you cannot open the link I hope you understand how it works.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <input 
          v-if="showA" 
          type="text" 
          v-model="inputA" 
          @focusin="visibleA = true" 
          @focusout="visibleA = false">
    
    <input 
           v-if="showB" 
           type="text" 
            v-model="inputB"
           @focusin="visibleB = true"
           @focusout="visibleB = false">
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="hide">
    <h5>{{ inputA }} </h5>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hide: false,
      inputA: '',
      inputB: '',
      visibleA: false,
      visibleB: false,
    };
  },
  
  computed: {
    showA() {
      return (this.inputA.length > 0 || !this.hide) || this.visibleA;
    },
    
    showB() {
      return (this.inputB.length > 0 || !this.hide) || this.visibleB;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Off course you could do that in many other ways, and maybe this one is not the best possible, but it shows my point.

PS: If you have dozens of input box, I recommends you to create a component to handle that logic, and then you just receive an `hide` props in your component and emits `input` for example.

Comment: I updated the question with your answer. But After I apply my above code, when I check the checkbox it impossible to edit. How can i fix it?